# Sefer of Ari Z''L's Changes in Tefillah

Tags: prayer-book, chasidut-hasidism

Does anyone know of a sefer that lists the Ari Z''L's changes in Tefillah?  I do not mean a siddur itself (e.g. Tehillas Hashem), rather, I am referring to a book that outlines the changes preferably with reasons given.

Comment: When you say Arizal do you mean the CHABAD Arizal or regular Nesuach Sefarad?

Comment: I have a friend who has a siddur that compares the nusach of the Sepharadim from before the Ari Z"L with the kabbalistic emendations that the Ari Z"L made (and from which stem modern sephardic siddurim). Note that Chabad's siddur, Tehillat Hashem, is *not* what the Ari Z"L's manuscripts said the siddur should be -- the author of that siddur made no such claim. He says in the introduction that there were certain parts of the  Ari Z"L's manuscripts/notes don't accord with Halacha, and therefore others that came along later had to reconcile the kabbalah with the halacha.

Comment: @Chanoch can you please tell me what the name of that Siddur? Or when I can get it?

Comment: @H'Gabriel: it's the one I mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to the changes as featured in the Ba'al HaTanya's *siddur*, then [Sha'ar HaKolel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16002&pgnum=1) is the *sefer* you are looking for.

Comment: Also Dayan Raskin's notes on the siddur, which complement the Shaar HaKollel. This is available at http://www.hebrewbooks.org/30450.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for סידור האר״י :‏ ‏תפילת חיים which takes the original siddur from which the Ari z"l based his changes, and finds the changes he made in the kitvei Ari.

- [On WorldCat if you want it from a library](http://www.worldcat.org/title/sidur-ha-ari-tefilat-hayim/oclc/062320383)
- [From a seforim store](http://www.discountseforim.com/Hebrew-Seforim-ISS14100.html)

Comment: Your second link is broken.